# Using Alt+F4 in X2Go?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, x2go

When I run a remote Linux desktop from Windows 10 through X2Go with `vxnsvr` and the `-keyhook` option, most key pressed are forwarded and interpreted by the remote system, e.g. <kbd>Meta/Win</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>.

Not so for <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd>, which gives me the popup shown below, i.e. Alt+F4 is interpreted by Windows instead of the remote desktop.

Is it possible to get complete forwarding?

[image]

Comment: Not that it answers your question.. but what does x2go do that forwarding x11 doesn't?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas X2Go serves as intermediate layer improving performance and providing session management (i.e. you don't lose your desktop session, if the connection gets interrupted). It also comes preconfigured for this use, making it easier to use in everyday settings, especially when the local machine is running Windows. The cause of my issue is most likely with the local X-server, not with X2Go though, but I cannot be sure.